# ListView with a custom Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I have a listView with custom layout, I used PlaceHolder concept to manage the ideas. 
List view the list of all contacts from the mobile .
and the layout enables user to select some of them .

The custom layout consists of a textbox , an image and a checkbox

And this a Array Adapter code 
i used my own ArrayAdapter and filled the fields in its getView method 
This is code :

```
     public class customContactAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

public final Activity context ;
public final List<String> ContactList;


public customContactAdapter(Activity context, int resource, List<String> objects)
{
    super(context, resource, objects);
    this.context= context;
    this.ContactList= objects;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //View vi ;
    //vi= convertView;
    final ViewHolder MyHolder ;
    if ( convertView==null){

        MyHolder= new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        convertView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.number_layout,null,true);

        MyHolder.txtContact = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ContactName);
        MyHolder.RingMode = ( ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RingMode);
        MyHolder.CheckedContact = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        MyHolder.MainLayout =(RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.MainLayout);

        convertView.setTag(MyHolder);

    }else{
        MyHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }


    MyHolder.txtContact.setText(ContactList.get(position));
    String _Mode="";

    try{

        DataBase db = new DataBase(context);
        db.open();
        _Mode= db.GetContactRow(ContactList.get(position));
        db.close();

    }catch(Exception e ){
        Log.w("Error in getting mde from databse ",e.toString());
    }


    if (_Mode!=""){
        Log.w("Contact is selected:","YES");
        MyHolder.CheckedContact.setChecked(true);

        if ( _Mode=="0"){
            MyHolder.RingMode.setImageResource(R.drawable.silent3);
        }else if (_Mode=="1"){
            MyHolder.RingMode.setImageResource(R.drawable.vibration3);
        }else if (_Mode=="2"){
            MyHolder.RingMode.setImageResource(R.drawable.ring3);
        }
    }else {
        MyHolder.RingMode.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
    }


    if (position % 2 == 1)
    {
        MyHolder.MainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E8E5E9"));
    }
    else{
        MyHolder.MainLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#C8E6C9"));
    }

    return convertView ;
}

public class ViewHolder{
    private TextView txtContact;
    private ImageView RingMode;
    private CheckBox CheckedContact;
    private RelativeLayout MainLayout;
}
}
```

the problem is that when i checked a checkbox in a row then the nest seventh checkbox is also checked .
Why this happening ?
Whole row is not repeating. The data is showing distinctly but only checked checkbox repeats itself.

And one more thing how can i get the clicked row's layout.
i want that when user clicks on the row then the checkbox will checked.

Thanks in advance because finding a problem from this much code is really brave work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since the rows of your listview might be **reused** by the listview, it's possible that your `convertView` comes as an item that's already been checked before.

You'll have to explicitly write something like:

```
boolean isChecked = _Mode != "";
MyHolder.CheckedContact.setChecked(isChecked);
```

Please note: Your code has several issues. Don't access your database in the `getView()` method. Instead, firstly store the items to an array/a list in your adapter, and simply call list.get(position) in the `getView()` method.

Also, you don't need to store the context as a field in your adapter, because you can call `parent.getContext()` where needed.
In general, the `getView()` method should run **as fast as possible** to allow smooth scrolling.

Lastly, your code would be much more readable if you followed the [Java Code Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html).